# cannot read property 'length' of undefined in angular

Tags: json, angularjs

I have an json array and i am trying to get the length of that array but i am getting an error of undefined.

```
 $http.post('http://localhost:8099/mescc/seci/tools/ManageSettings',addOrUpdateJson)
        .success(
            function(dat, status,
                headers, config) {
                 $scope.loading=false;
                 $scope.table=true;
                 $scope.allConfigDatabase = dat;

                 for (var i = 0, len = dat.data.length; i < len; i++)  
                 {
                    $scope.editingData[$scope.allConfigDatabase.data[i].id] = false;
                 }
                 $scope.searchParameter = "";
                 $scope.updateView=false;
                 $scope.$apply();
                })
                .error(
                function(data, status,headers, config) {                                        
           });
```

Comment: have you checked to see what dat.data is? dat might not be what you expect it to be

Comment: clearly `dat.data` is undefined, not an array.

Answer (score 0):

The response of the POST request is in your 'dat' parameter of the success function. I'm pointing that just because I see a you use 'data' for the error function, maybe a previous rename had caused the error.

This 'undefined' error, means that your json response doesn't have a 'data' property. To be clearer, it doesn't look like:

```
{ foo: {}, bar: {}, data:[1,2,3,4] }
```

You can use the utility function provided by angular to better check on the client side:

```
if (angular.isArray(dat.data)) {
  //...
}
```